# Improve performance updating the DOM using Datatables jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, dom, datatables

I wonder if there's any way to speed up `fnUpdate` function when applying it to many rows.
In my case I am using it to update for example 10 cells of 10 different rows and I am noticing it is not so fast as expected. Its a bit laggy.

[I've seen](http://devongovett.wordpress.com/2009/12/08/jquery-dom-manipulation-at-lighting-speeds/) than a common technique to improve the performance when updating the DOM is to to do it at once instead of looping. This way, the browser will only reflow the page once and will speed up the process.

Is there any way to do it in datatables plugin making of of [fnUpdate function](http://www.datatables.net/api)? Thanks.

Comment: How many rows are being displayed at once? The best way to speed up DataTables is by paginating.

Comment: I can be displaying around 50 or 100 rows. I'd rather prefer not to use pagination. For the user this is a faster way to have an overview.

Comment: Update your original data object and pass it entirely into the fnUpdate method rather than passing each row one at a time.

Comment: @KevinB Can you explain it a bit more? The data is obtained from the DB, but it would be even slower to make another call against it.

Comment: You already have the original data, just update that original data with the new data where appropriate. No need to go back to the database.

Comment: @KevinB I don't get it. what is the difference with what I am doing?

Comment: Well, to be honest i can't see your code, so i don't know what you are doing. If you are referring to calling fnUpdate 1 time vs 10 times, calling it once with multiple row updates should be more efficient than calling it 10 times each with a separate row update.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25851/discussion-between-steve-and-kevin-b)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be helpful that you try the 4th and 5th option of fnUpdate, which disables updating the entire table right after updating the cell. You can do the whole table update when all changes are done.

> for(i = 0; i < rows ; i++)
>       {
>           dataTable.fnUpdate( "Sample Data", i, 3, false, false );
>       }
>     dataTable.fnDraw();

Comment: I used this approach and it took the loop routine from 600ms to 3ms.